# Number of natural solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + 2x_4 + x_5 = 72$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, diophantine-equations

What are the number of natural solutions to
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + 2x_4 + x_5 = 72$$ where $x_1 \ge 2, x_2, x_3 \ge 1, x_4, x_5 \ge 0$?

I understand how to do it if it wasn't "$2x_4$", hence if the coefficient of $x_4$ was $1$, , then the answer will be $C(72,4) \ldots \ $, but given $2x_4$, I don't know how to solve the question.

Comment: Please note that if you only had $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 72$ the answer would **not** be $C(72, 4)$.

Comment: @RSerrao: Yes, it would: in effect you’re counting non-negative solutions to $x_1+\ldots+x_5=68$.

Comment: Yeah, the 2x4 confuses me.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott what do you mean? Isn't the $C(72, 4) $ the same as ${72\choose {4}} $?

Comment: No, it wouldnt, since you have 72 - 2 (for x1), - 1 (for x2) - 1 (for x3) = 68.

Comment: @RSerrao: Yes, and that’s the answer: $\binom{68+(5-1)}{5-1}=\binom{72}4$.

Comment: Brian did you delete your post? I cant see

Comment: @Dharm1k: Yes, I did, because I misread the original problem and didn’t at first realize that $x_2$ was required to be at least $1$ as well as $x_3$. What I had will require a bit of work to fix.

Comment: Is RSerrao's solution correct?

Comment: @Dharm1k: Yes, but I think that it’s possible to find a way to evaluate that sum more easily.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks for the help, I did confuse two different things when answering Dharm1k on the comments

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2036289/how-many-integer-solutions-to-the-following-equation/2037155#2037155

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move $2x_4$ to the other side and solve a separate $4$-variable problem for each possible value of $x_4$. In other words, you’re counting non-negative solutions to

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_5=68-2k$$

for $k=0,\ldots,34$, and you get

$$\sum_{k=0}^{34}\binom{71-2k}3=\sum_{k=1}^{35}\binom{2k+1}3\;.$$

This actually isn’t quite as nasty as it may look. If we calculate the first few values of $$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{2k+1}3\;,$$ we get $a_1=1$, $a_2=10$, $a_3=35$, and $a_4=84$, with first differences $9$, $25$, and $49$. That suggests that we’re looking at sums of odd squares, i.e., that

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{2k}3&=\sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)^2\\
&=4\sum_{k=1}^nk^2-4\sum_{k=1}^nk+\sum_{k=1}^n1\\
&=\frac23n(n+1)(2n+1)-2n(n+1)+n\\
&=\frac13n(4n^2-1)\;.
\end{align*}$$

This can be straightforwardly proved by induction on $n$.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Thanks @Brian M. Scott for enlightening me. I was confusing two different things.

First up, the different conditions

$$x_1 \ge 2; x_2, x_3 \ge 1; x_4, x_5 \ge 0$$

are rather inconvenient. Let us change the problem to finding the solutions of

$$y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + 2y_4 + y_5 = 68$$ with $y_i \ge 0\ \forall_{i \le 5}$

Where we subtracted 2 from $x_1$ and subtracted 1 from each $x_2$ and $x_3$. But then again it is quite inconvenient to have the 2 factor in the middle of the expression. Let us move it to the beginning, shall we? Renaming the variables, we want to solve

$$2x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 68, x_i \ge 0$$

right? If you fix the value of $x_1 = 2k$, then you want to solve

$$x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 68 - 2k, x_i \ge 0$$

right? But that is an easily solvable problem. Since the number of solutions of that equation is given by $C(68 - 2k, 4)$, your answer is just summing up through all values of $68 - 2k$:

$$\sum_{i = 0}^{34} C(68 - 2k, 4)$$

Comment: What would the summation be in terms of combination, would it be C(68-2k,4)?

Comment: I havent done any recurrence yet, how would i do use in combination

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$$
\bbx{\ds{\mbox{This answer provides a}\ \underline{numerical}\ \mbox{result}:\
\color{#f00}{528,990}}}
$$

> What are the number of integer solutions to
>   \begin{equation}
> x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + 2x_{4} + x_{5} = 72\ ?\quad\mbox{where}\quad
> x_{1} \geq 2\,;\quad\ x_{2}\,,\ x_{3} \geq 1\,;\quad\ x_{4}\,,\ x_{5} \geq 0
> \label{1}\tag{1}
> \end{equation}

That is given by
\begin{align}
&\sum_{x_{1} = 2}^{\infty}\ \sum_{x_{2} = 1}^{\infty}\
\sum_{x_{3} = 1}^{\infty}\ \sum_{x_{4} = 0}^{\infty}\ \sum_{x_{5} = 0}^{\infty}
\bracks{x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + 2x_{4} + x_{5} = 72}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{x_{1} = 0}^{\infty}\ \sum_{x_{2} = 0}^{\infty}\
\sum_{x_{3} = 0}^{\infty}\ \sum_{x_{4} = 0}^{\infty}\ \sum_{x_{5} = 0}^{\infty}
\bracks{x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + 2x_{4} + x_{5} = 68} = 
\bracks{z^{68}}\bracks{1 \over \pars{1 - z}^{5}\pars{1 + z}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbox[#ffe,15px,border:2px dotted navy]{\ds{528,990}}
\end{align}