# How many integer solutions to the following equation?

Tags: combinations, probability

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + 2x_4 + x_5 = 72$ where

$x_1 \geq 2,$

$x_2, x_3 \geq 1, $

$x_4, x_5 \geq 0.$

I understand how to do it if it was no $2x_4$ but just $x_4$, then its ${72}\choose{4}$. What about with the $2x_4$?

Comment: This is a site for programming questions.

Comment: sry im new to stack

Answer (score 1):

This is same as the coefficient of $t^{72}$ in
\begin{align*}
&(t^2+t^3+\cdots)(t+t^2+\cdots)^2(1+t^2+t^4+\cdots)(1+t+t^2+\cdots) \\
&=t^4(1+t+t^2+\cdots)^4(1+t^2+\cdots)\\
&= \frac{t^4}{(1-t)^4(1-t^2)}\\
&=\frac{t^4}{(1-t)^5(1+t)}\\
&=t^4\left(\frac{1/32}{1+t} + \frac{1/32}{1-t}+\frac{1/16}{(1-t)^2}+\frac{1/8}{(1-t)^3}+\frac{1/4}{(1-t)^4}+\frac{1/2}{(1-t)^5} \right)
\end{align*}
The above partial fraction expression was obtained using Sagemath.
The coefficient of $t^k$ in $(1-t)^{-n}$ is $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$. Thus the required number of ways is 
$$\frac{1}{32}+\frac{1}{32} + \frac{1}{16}\binom{2+68-1}{68}+\frac{1}{8}\binom{3+68-1}{68}+\frac{1}{4}\binom{4+68-1}{68}+\frac{1}{2}\binom{5+68-1}{68} $$
$$=\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{16}\binom{69}{1} +\frac{1}{8}\binom{70}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\binom{71}{3}+\frac{1}{2}\binom{72}{4} = 528990$$

Putting $\frac{1}{(1-t)^4(1+t)}$ may be cumbersome to accomplish (for which we have used SAGEMATH). However, I realized that there is a pattern in the partial fraction coefficients that led me to the following generalization:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-t} + \frac{2}{(1-t)^2} + \cdots + \frac{2^{n-1}}{(1-t)^n}
&= \frac{1}{1-t}\left(\frac{1 - \frac{2^n}{(1-t)^n}}{1-\frac{2}{1-t}}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{1-t}\left(\frac{1 - \frac{2^n}{(1-t)^n}}{-\frac{1+t}{1-t}} \right)\\
&= -\frac{1}{1+t} + \frac{2^n}{(1+t)(1-t)^n} \\
\end{align*}
and hence
$$\frac{1}{(1+t)(1-t)^n} = \frac{1}{2^n}\left(\frac{1}{1+t} + \frac{1}{1-t} + \frac{2}{(1-t)^2} + \cdots + \frac{2^{n-1}}{(1-t)^n}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Firstly place $2$ in $x_1$, $1$ each in $x_2,x_3,$, then we can write it as $X_1+X_2+X_3+X_5 = 68-2X_4, X_i \ge 0, X_4\le34$

Using stars and bars, we can write the answer as as $$\sum_{j=0}^{34} \binom{71-2j}3$$

Comment: how did u get that combination tho?

Comment: if  you did 68-2X4, you proves why you use 3 dividers, but why do you do 71-2J, where does that come from?

Comment: The stars and bars formula is $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ for $n$ stars and $k$ boxes (hence $k-1$ bars or dividers). The upper index here is $(68-2j+4-1) =(71-2j)$ to be put in $4$ boxes $\boxed{X_1}\; |\; \boxed{X_2}\; |\; \boxed{X_3}\; |\; \boxed{X_5}$, so only $3$ dividers. You should look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics). The answer I also get is $528990$

Comment: Okay, and we must do summation because the x4 can be many possibilities? right?

Comment: Yes, that\s right !

Comment: The sum$\sum_{j=0}^{34} \binom{71-2j}{3} $ can be computed as follows:  \begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^{34} \binom{71-2j}{3} &= \binom{71}{3}+\binom{69}{3}+\cdots +\binom{3}{3}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{34} \binom{3+2k}{3} \\
&=  \frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=0}^{34} (3+2k)(2+2k)(1+2k) \\
&= \frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=0}^{34} (8k^3+24k^2+22k+6) \\
&=\frac{1}{6}\left(8\times \left(\frac{34 \cdot 35}{2}\right)^2 + 24\times \frac{34 \cdot 35 \cdot 69}{6} + 22 \times \frac{34 \cdot 35}{2} + 6 \times 35\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{6}(2832200 + 328440 + 13090 + 210)\\
&=528990
\end{align*}